# Playing Video in SDL 2.0.4 (Theora)

Tags: c++, video, sdl, playback, ogg-theora

I'm using: UBUNTU 14.04 + SDL 2.0.4 + Code::Blocks 13.12 - (**C++**) - linked to **libtheora.a** (v.1.1.1)

**TARGET: To be able to play *(decode)* Ogg Theora video in an SDL2 application.**
I could use ffmpeg library. But there are licences issues because they use MPEG... *etc...*
So, I've choose Ogg Theora library from http://www.theora.org since is "patented free".
*(They have a simple and very permissive licence, no "proprietary" codecs in use).*

I've been searching in the web for a **very simple** SDL2 + Ogg Theora video play example in C++, **no need to decode audio, only video, in my case, and send to SDL2 (to a texture maybe?...)**. But I cant found anything related. I found only some "messy" code, even so, that doesn't worked.

Anyone can share a code snippet (any solution / any tips / other ideas)?...

*The code that I have so far...

(In this testing, I'm using "theoraplay.h" -- https://icculus.org/theoraplay -- at this moment)*

```all
// My project linkage:
-lSDL2
-lSDL2_image
-lSDL2_mixer
-logg
-lvorbis
-lvorbisenc
-lvorbisfile
-ltheora
-ltheoraenc
-ltheoradec

// SDL2:
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>

// OGG Library: (The multimedia wrapper)
#include "ogg/ogg.h"

// VORBIS Library: (Audio)
#include "vorbis/codec.h"
#include "vorbis/vorbisenc.h"
#include "vorbis/vorbisfile.h"

// THEORA Library: (Video)
#include "theora/theora.h"
#include "theora/theoraenc.h"
#include "theora/theoradec.h"    

// The "framework" for Ogg Theora video play, from: https://icculus.org/theoraplay      
// I'm Testing it... 
#include "theoraplay.h"


// SDL2 - Objects:
SDL_Surface* surface;
SDL_Texture* texture;
SDL_Rect rectangle;

// THEORAPLAY - Objects:
THEORAPLAY_Decoder* decoder = NULL; // Will return a Link error... Why?...
const THEORAPLAY_VideoFrame* video = NULL;  // No issues (Links and runs ok)
const THEORAPLAY_AudioPacket* audio = NULL; // No issues (Links and runs ok)




int main(int args, char* argv[]){

   // (SDL2 code to create the window, renderer, events, etc, goes here...) 

   surface = IMG_Load("images/example.png"); // Load an image.       
   texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, temp); // Pass the image into a texture.

   // "ERROR" - LOG says: undefined reference to "THEORAPLAY_startDecodeFile"...
   decoder = THEORAPLAY_startDecodeFile("bunny.ogg", 20, THEORAPLAY_VIDFMT_YV12);
   // "bunny.ogg" - Ogg video from: https://peach.blender.org/download

   // SDL2: Here, will be added the code to pass THEORA frames into a SDL2 streaming texture...

   while(!quit){

      // Render everything:
      SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rectangle);

   };

};
```